# How to use the Java 8 Duration.of(amount, unit) method?

Tags: java, duration

I tried this: Duration.of(3, SECONDS) as per the example, but what is the SECONDS constant coming from? It's not evaluating to anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a value from the [`ChronoUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum, implementing [`TemporalUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) - your code can be written as:

```
Duration.of(3, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "it's not evaluating to anything" - it's specifying what units you want to use.

Presumably you're using it without explicitly specifying `ChronoUnit` due to a staic import.

Personally I'd use `Duration.ofSeconds(3)` though, as I find that clearer.

Comment: I'm just following what's on JavaDoc: Obtains a Duration representing an amount in the specified unit. 

The parameters represent the two parts of a phrase like '6 Hours'. For example: 

  Duration.of(3, SECONDS);
  Duration.of(465, HOURS);

Comment: @user3804927: Right, then that presumably implies a static import (e.g. `import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.*;`)

Comment: Oh and I do agree with you regarding the use of .ofSeconds. However the fact that SECONDS come after the number makes it better suited for me semantically... However if I have to use ChronoUnit.SECONDS then it be rather cumbersome.

Comment: Just saw your other comment. This is exactly what I needed, thanks :)

Comment: @user3804927: well you don't, because you can use a static import.

Answer (score 3):

The `SECONDS` constant, along with the other time constants, come from the [`ChronoUnit` enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).